# Is it possible to use same kind of two references in one project?

Tags: vb.net, browser, mshtml

i'm developing a project which fetch some information from web to windows form so i'm using ***mshtml*** reference . so i can convert the document in below way

> Dim docDell As HTMLDocument = CType(WebBrowser1.Document.DomDocument,
>   mshtml.HTMLDocument)

above code works great !

but when i try the below code its shows the warning message***(runtime error might occur when converting 'system.windows.forms.htmldocument' to mshtml.IhtmlDocument)***

> Dim newdoc As HTMLDocument = WebBrowser1.Document

Is that any way to use both in same project ...

Hope i explained well ..

Comment: What type do you want the `newdoc` variable to be?  Do you want it to be a `System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument` or an `mshtml.HtmlDocument` variable?

Comment: Ok .Let me explain more .. there are many forms are there in my project(lets say form1,form2 etc) each form fetches information from various site ). for some forms i'm in the situation to use Mshtml reference so i have included the mshtml reference, for other forms i can handle the webpages by using System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument. Yes i want to use >System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both in the same project.  You just need to be careful about which namespace you are using.  Since `System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument` and `mshtml.HtmlDocument` both share the same class name, you need to make sure you are using the correct one by specifying the right namespace.

Here's how you'd get the two objects from the same `WebBrowser`:

```
Dim unmanagedDoc As mshtml.HtmlDocument = DirectCast(WebBrowser1.Document.DomDocument, mshtml.HTMLDocument)
Dim managedDoc As System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument = WebBrowser1.Document
```

Comment: Working !! . Well Explained :)